# Remover cor de fundo do input no autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Algo que me deixa muito incomodado é quando o navegador do google autocompleta algo e deixa o input com fundo amarelo, como posso remover isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é meio gambiarra, mas deve resolver seu problema :)

```css
/* Trocar para branco qualquer cor */
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```